# Center align the overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I have a website: [Its resolved now so haveto remove the site URL] in which overlay is coming up on hover of thumbnails. 
Its working just fine on Firefox browser but its not working fine on Chromium browsers and the content div is aligned more towards the left side. Can anyone please tell me using firebug or inpect element tool on above mentioned site how to align the overlay content div to center as well just like its coming on firefox?

Please note it gets fixed if I set width to 100% but I want the width to be adjusted automatically just like the height.

I tried following code but it didn't work:

```
.project-title {
    max-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto!important;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #202020 !important;
    background-color:#dbdbdb;
    font-family: Lato !important;
    font-size: 12pt !important;
    }
```

Comment: Please note it gets fixed if I set width to 100% but I want the width to be adjusted automatically just like the height.

Comment: Can you add also some HTML and use a snippet to show your issue. SEE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to center align in two different ways.  You shouldn't have the `margin:auto` if you're using `position:absolute;`  They won't do anything for you.

If you want to center align a div, there's hundreds of ways of doing that.  Here's two simple ones:

```
.project-title {
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

or

```
.project-title {
    width:250px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-125px;
}
```

A more advanced way, depending on how the rest of your stuff is set up, is something like this:

```
.project-title {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This will center it inside of it's containing div.

To help you more, I'll need to know what is containing your div and what the expected behavior to be.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. 3rd one worked for me. I added a fall back with CSS and loading these new lines for only safari and chromium browsers

Comment: @JamesPablo, Great! I'm glad I could help!  The third one is very powerful.  you can make your div any size and it will always be centered in it's parent (or the closest parent with a `position` attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You've positioned `.project-title` absolutely, so it's taken out of the normal flow of the page. Therefore `margin: auto` trick won't work.

Something like the below may do it:

```
.project-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```